# Calculating residue of $f(z) = \frac{(z^2 - 1)^4}{z^5}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Calculate the residue of  $$f(z) = \frac{(z^2 - 1)^4}{z^5}$$ in $z = 0$

I let $g(z) = (z^2 - 1)^4.$

I'm using a theorem which states:

> Suppose $g$ is holomorphic around $z = \alpha$ and that $N$ is a
>   positive integer, then $$RES_{z=\alpha}\frac{g(z)}{(z-\alpha)^N} =
>  \frac{g^{(N-1)}(\alpha)}{(N-1)!}$$

and I get the correct answer (since $g(z) / (z-0)^5 = f(z))$, however, it is really annoying to have to differentiate that many times. **Is there a smarter method?**

Comment: How about using the binomial theorem? it gives you that the coefficient of $z^{4}$ of $(z^{2}-1)^{4}$ is 6.

Comment: Find the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The residue is related to the coefficient of $1/z$

> Namely $$f(z) = \cdots a_{-2}/z^2 +a_{-1}/z+a_0 +a_{1}z \cdots \implies Res(f,0) = a_{-1}$$

but we have the factor $1/z^5$ therefore it suffices to determine the factor $z^4$ in  the term $(z^2-1)^4$
 which is given by $$(z^2 -1)^4 = 6 z^4 +rest(z)  $$

Hence the coefficient of $1/z$ in $f$ is

$$ 6/z$$
Hence

$$Res(f,0) = 6$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{(z^2 - 1)^4}{z^5}
= \frac{z^8 - 4 z^6 + 6 z^4 - 4 z^2 + 1}{z^5}
= \cdots + \frac{6}{z} + \cdots
$$